# Hidden Features of VHDL

Tags: vhdl

The original question was:

What are some really useful but esoteric language features in VHDL that you've actually been able to employ to do useful work?

The original question was deleted, and I was just answering. I think this is an interesting question, especially when you compare VHDL to other (normal) programming languages.

Disclaimer: I only did few trivial examples in VHDL.

But what I especially liked, when compared to other programming languages (which is probably not what you are asking about, but I think just for these things every programmer should know VHDL a bit):

1. The ability to have several different implementations (architectures) of a single interface, and exchange them easily.
2. The low-overhead parallelism inherent to the language model. It sort of reminds me of dataflow languages.

Comment: Make it a CW ... you are tempting me to close.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. If you can, do it please.

Answer (score 7):

> What are some really useful but esoteric language features in VHDL...

User-defined physical types like "angle", "voltage", "temperature_coefficient",  where you can then write stuff like `temp <= 45 deg;` or `volt <= 3.3 V;`.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, there are more than one way to do something. OK, *most of the time*, you can do things in many ways in VHDL. Look at situation where you want to assign different values to a signal, based on the value of another signal.

**Selected Signal Assignment**

The most specific way to do this is with as selected signal assignment. Based on several possible values of `b`, you assign a value to `a`. No redundancy in the code here.

```
with a select b <=
        "1000" when "00",
        "0100" when "01",
        "0010" when "10",
        "0001" when "11";
```

**Conditional Signal Assignment**

The construct of a *conditional signal assignment* is a little more general. For each option, you have to give a condition. This means that you could write any boolean expression as a condition, which give you more freedom than equality checking. While this construct would give you more freedom, there is a bit more redundancy too. We had to write the equality check (`a =`) on every line. If you use a signal with a long name, this will make your code bulkier. Also, the separator that's used in the selected signal assingment was a comma. In the conditional signal assingment, you need the `else` keyword. More code for the same functionality.

```
b <= "1000" when a = "00" else 
         "1000" when a = "01" else 
         "1000" when a = "10" else 
         "1000" when a = "11";
```

**Combinational Process with Case Statement**

The most generally usable construct is a process. Inside this process, you can write a case statement, or a cascade of if statements. There is even more redundancy here. You the skeleton code for a process (begin, end) and the sensitivity list. That's not a big effort, but while I was drafting this, I had put `b` in the sensitivity list instead of `a`. Easy to make a small misstake. You also need to specify what happens in the `other` cases.

```
process(a)
begin
        case a is
                when "00" => b <= "1000";
                when "01" => b <= "0100";
                when "10" => b <= "0010";
                when "11" => b <= "0001";
                when others => assert "unreachable" severity failure;
        end case;
end process;
```

While this last code snippet is the largest and perhaps most error-prone, it is probably also the most common. It uses two familiar and often-used constructs: the process and the case statements.

The problem with the selected and conditional signal assignments is that there is no system in their syntax. The meaning is *almost* identical, but the syntax is just different enough to throw you off. I know *many* engineers who permanently have a copy of the Doulos Golden Reference Guide to VHDL lying on their desks. Which is good for Doulos, because their name gets mentioned all the time.

Answer (score 5):

The best feature of VHDL — that it is used to design and implement hardware. :)

> The ability to have several different implementations (architectures) of a single interface, and exchange them easily.

The same with OOP in C++: you can define one interface and many implementations. It is very useful in VHDL to create simulation and synthesis models for the same device.

> The low-overhead parallelism inherent to the language model. It sort of reminds me of dataflow languages.

Actually, there is SystemC library to C++ which implements parallel execution semantics. You can easily download and try this: http://www.systemc.org. I'm working on C++-to-RTL synthesis. So I hope in 4-5 years all hardware development will be done using SystemC and C++.

Comment: Why? VHDL was created by EE's, for EE's. It contains all it needs and is straight-forward. Why add another layer onto it?

Answer (score 2):

> What are some really useful but
>   esoteric language features in VHDL

Firstly, I don't buy into the theory that VHDL has 'esoteric' features.  However, the prevalent 'styles' of VHDL that exist in the wild are most often influenced by what subset of VHDL is supported by hardware synthesizers.

The equation in the VHDL world is very simple: if tools support a language subset, it will be used.  If not, the feature will likely be underused.

> especially when you compare VHDL to other (normal) programming languages.

Note that VHDL is not a programming language.  Rather, it is a language for describing discrete event systems (with an 'accidental' consequence that it can be used to describe digital hardware).  I suppose that the comparison to programming languages stems from VHDL looking like some actual programming languages.

Now on to some actual answers to the OP's question.

> What are some really useful but esoteric language features in VHDL...

Here's my pick, in no particular order.

1. *Architectures:*  By far, the ability to select different architectures for an interface is the most useful feature VHDL has and which is being used at all times.
2. *Generators:* using generators you can pretty easily describe complex regular hardware structures.  Think multipliers, adders, complex pipelines and the like.  Unfortunately, many tools make a mess out of the generated output.
3. *Blocks:* A cheap way to sub-divide your design into sub-blocks; not all tools support it though.
4. *Signal resolution:*  Rather useful when simulating circuits and the like, not so for hardware synthesis.
5. *Attributes:*  A great way to attach instructions to the simulator/synthesizer to help it out in finding the best way to implement your circuit.  While this can in most cases be done with command line options to the synthesizer/mapper/p&r tools, attributes feel much more natural, as all the info needed to produce your piece of hardware is confined to a single place.

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few of VHDL's "esoteric" features have their origin in Ada. I mention this because I'm not an Ada expert, but learning Ada has greatly improved my vision of what can be accomplished in VHDL.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional signal assignment is the same as a case statement - i.e. equal weight branches. Selected signal assignment is a priority encoder structure  - i.e. equivalent to nested if/then/else statements. Note that all concurrent assignment statements in vhdl are identically equivalent to a process with a sensitivity list composed of the signals on the right hand side of the assignment operator.

My favourite esoteric features are configurations (which are especially useful when you have multiple architectures of the same entity) and access types. These allow one to create dynamic data structures. Not useful for hardware design, but very useful for testbench creation. Method overloading my argument type signature also makes for very readable code - and is a feature sadly lacking in SystemVerilog.

Paul.

Comment: Oops - I have it backwards. Of course, selected signal assignments are equivalent to case statements and conditional assignments are equivalent to nested if/then/else.

Answer (score 0):

The most esoteric thing I know is the combination of three principles:

1. character literal: '\'
2. extended identifier: \'bar\
3. attributes: identifier'attribute

Now what is this expression?:  foo'\'bar\
It is the \'bar\ attribute of foo.

I guess no vhdl lexer survives this.

Comment: Something called [IR-1045](http://www.eda.org/isac/IRs-VHDL-93/IR1045.txt)  from the VHDL 93 issues.   foo'\'bar\ can be disambiguated by a lexer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have signals in a package.
2. You can create new ports in a configuration.
3. You can overload functions based on return type.
4. You can define signals in an entity, that can be used from the architecture. This is not useful for anything that I know of, but it's there.